# How to uncheck all when the other radial is picked

Tags: javascript, html

I create a js for my project. It almost work except that I need to uncheck all checkbox under first radial when second radial is picked.

[image: Radial-Uncheck]

JS

```
<script>

    function habilitarSecciones(selected) {
        var chk = $(selected);
        var checked = chk.is(":checked");
        var id = chk.val();

        $("[id^='Grp2']").attr("disabled", true);

        if (checked) {
            $(".Grp2_" + id).removeAttr("disabled", false);

        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <h3>Tipo</h3>
            @foreach (Dominio.Tipo tipo in Model.Secciones.Select(x => x.Tipo).Distinct())
            {
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="@tipo.Id" name="Grp_Tipo" id='Grp_@tipo.Id' onclick="habilitarSecciones(this);" /> @tipo.Descrip
                </label>

                <hr />
                foreach (var seccion in Model.Secciones.Where(x => x.Tipo == tipo))
                {
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="Grp2_@tipo.Id" value="@seccion.Id" name="SeccionesElegidas" id="Grp2_@seccion.Id" disabled /> @seccion.Descrip
                    </label>
                }

                <hr />
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: If you have some actual generated HTML for your example that would make things a bit easier.  My Spanish is not the best.  Too set the checked status of a checkbox I think you can set the attribute for the element with jquery, e.g., .attr('checked', true); so just select those and set them to false.

Answer (score 0):

Please to try with `$('element').prop('checked', false);`